# How to get top 5 keywords if they are stored in an array

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

Using PostgreSQL, I need to find top 5 search keywords which are stored in an array field (keywords text [] NULL).
If it was not an array I could simply use:

```
     select count(*), keyword
     from search_table
     group by keyword
```

My keywords are stored in the array field and arrays are nee to me.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you want to do this in PostgreSQL, why did you tag it as 'oracle'?

Comment: @EdStevens: I re-tagged it for PostgreSQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use unnest() to turn an array into a table.

```
SELECT kw, count(*) FROM (SELECT unnest(keywords) kw FROM thetable) AS x GROUP BY kw
```